# JPA request problem : Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a problem with my JPA request.
I work on a spring project with spring MVC, spring data on a TomCat server.

I've these tables :

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5C0JB.jpg)

I need, starting from the ID of a document, to find the questions and answers related to it.
It's something like that in SQL :

```
Select * from quizz_question, quizz_answer
where quizz_question.id = ( Select question_id from document_question Where document_id = 4406585 )
and quizz_answer.question_ID = quizz_question.id
```

My Document and QuizzQuestion entities are joined using the DOCUMENT_QUESTION table.

Document entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TAB_DOCUMENT)
public class Document implements Serializable, IEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CONTENT")
    @Lob
    private String content;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinTable(name = SopraTableConstants.TAB_DOCUMENT_QUESTION, 
        uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(name = SopraTableConstants.CONSTRAINT_UK_DOCUMENT_QUESTION, columnNames = {"DOCUMENT_ID","QUESTION_ID"}) }, 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }
    )
    @SortNatural
    private SortedSet<QuizzQuestion> questions=new TreeSet<QuizzQuestion>();

    /** @return the content */
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /** @return the questions */
    public SortedSet<QuizzQuestion> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    /** @param questions
     *            the questions to set */
    public void setQuestions(final SortedSet<QuizzQuestion> questions) {
        this.questions=questions;
    }
}
```

QuizzQuestion entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TAB_QUIZZ_QUESTION)
public class QuizzQuestion implements Serializable, IEntity<Long>, Comparable<QuizzQuestion> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String questionLabel;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name =  SopraTableConstants.FK_QUIZZ_ANSWER_QUIZZ_DOCUMENT))
    @SortNatural
    private SortedSet<QuizzAnswer> answers;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "QUIZZ_ANSWER_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name =  SopraTableConstants.FK_QUIZZ_RIGHT_ANSWER))
    private QuizzAnswer rightAnswer;

    public SortedSet<QuizzAnswer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getQuestionLabel() {
        return questionLabel;
    }

    public QuizzAnswer getRightAnswer() {
        return rightAnswer;
    }

    public void setAnswers(SortedSet<QuizzAnswer> param) {
        this.answers = param;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setQuestionLabel(String param) {
        this.questionLabel = param;
    }

    public void setRightAnswer(QuizzAnswer param) {
        this.rightAnswer = param;
    }
}
```

QuizzAnswer entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TAB_QUIZZ_ANSWER)
public class QuizzAnswer implements Serializable, IEntity<Long>, Comparable<QuizzAnswer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Pattern(regexp = ".{1,255}", message = "pattern")
    private String answerLabel;

    public String getAnswerLabel() {
        return answerLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setAnswerLabel(String param) {
        this.answerLabel = param;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

So I did something like this in JPA:

```
@Query(value = "select quest from Document doc"
        + " right join doc.questions quest"
        + " join quest.answers"
        + " where doc.id = :documentId"
)
List<QuizzQuestion> findQuestionsByDocumentId(@Param(value = "documentId") final Long documentId);
```

But several questions aris. I ask on the basic DOCUMENT table but I return a list of "QuizzQuestion" items. So do I have to perform this query in the "DocumentRepository" or "QuizzQuestionRepository" repository.

I've tried both, but in any case, the following errors are returned to me:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quizzQuestionRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.afklm.sopra.repository.QuizzQuestionRepository.findQuestionsByDocumentId(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1053)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.afklm.sopra.repository.QuizzQuestionRepository.findQuestionsByDocumentId(java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=quest,role=com.afklm.sopra.entity.Document.questions,tableName=QUIZZ_QUESTION,tableAlias=quizzquest2_,origin=DOCUMENT document0_,columns={document0_.ID ,className=com.afklm.sopra.entity.QuizzQuestion}}] [select quest from com.afklm.sopra.entity.Document doc right join fetch doc.questions quest join fetch quest.answers where doc.id = :documentId]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor60.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=quest,role=com.afklm.sopra.entity.Document.questions,tableName=QUIZZ_QUESTION,tableAlias=quizzquest2_,origin=DOCUMENT document0_,columns={document0_.ID ,className=com.afklm.sopra.entity.QuizzQuestion}}] [select quest from com.afklm.sopra.entity.Document doc right join fetch doc.questions quest join fetch quest.answers where doc.id = :documentId]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=quest,role=com.afklm.sopra.entity.Document.questions,tableName=QUIZZ_QUESTION,tableAlias=quizzquest2_,origin=DOCUMENT document0_,columns={document0_.ID ,className=com.afklm.sopra.entity.QuizzQuestion}}]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:923)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    ... 90 more
```

It's probably something easy to solve, but I'm a little lost. If anyone can enlighten me, thanks in advance to him! :D

Comment: The problem with you query is this: fetch = FetchType.EAGER, Remove it and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the query problem there are missing spaces:

As a good practice put them in the beginning of multiline string so you can see it.

Then you want to return QuizzQuestion so return these and not the Document:

```
@Query(value = "select quest from QuizzQuestion quest"
        + " join fetch quest.answers"
        + " where quest.document.id = :documentId"
)
List<QuizzQuestion> findQuestionsByDocumentId(@Param(value = "documentId") final Long documentId);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But now I-ve this error:
    query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list.
I've tried to remove the fetch from the joins, but it doesn't change anything...
I'm gonna have to do some training in JPA queries I think ^^

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. You have to rewrite the query. See my updated answer

Comment: The problem is that the document entity has a "question" attribute attached to the question table. But the question entity it does not have a "document" attribute. So I can make a doc.question but not a quest.document ... :/
Maybe I have to add this attribute to the question entity ?

Comment: Can you please post all attributes of both entities in the question. You can join also on any attributes

Comment: Oh it's a ManyToMany relationship. So unfortunately you cannot do this with JPQL you have to create a native SQL query.

Comment: No Problem. If you don't want the document attribute you can map the foreign key and then use the JOIN ON syntax Read more in my blog https://72.services/de/how-to-join-two-entities-without-mapped-relationship/

Comment: Ok, I've changed it to an OneToMany and used the query :
"select quest from Document doc join doc.questions quest join quest.answers where doc.id = :documentId". It works ! :D